# Get "MC machine" values from xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, getvalue

I have more xml file. I need to get the MC machine lines values. What is the simples way to get these values in vb.net?
These vaues are all times in "Attr num="123"" block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RadanCompoundDocument xmlns="http://www.radan.com/ns/rcd">
  <RadanAttributes>
    <Group class="system" name="System" desc="These attributes describe the RADAN system used to create this file."
        ord="8">
      <Attr num="13" name="Language" desc="RADAN language code." type="i" ord="1" value="19">
        <Valid perm="r"/>
      </Attr>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="15" name="Build" desc="RADAN software build." type="s" ord="3" value="2022.1.2228">
        <Valid perm="r"/>
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Manufacturing" desc="These attributes are the manufacturing properties of the file."
        ord="6">
      <Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1" value="Mild Steel">
        <Valid perm="e" max="100"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="120" name="Thickness" desc="Thickness." type="r" ord="2" value="1">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="121" name="Thickness units" desc="Thickness units." type="s" ord="4" value="mm">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="mm|in|swg" max="80"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="123" name="Cycle time" desc="Cycle time in minutes." type="r" ord="26" value="0">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
        <MC machine="psys_CAA001_1" value="10"/>
        <MC machine="psys_CAA001_2" value="20"/>
        <MC machine="psys_CAA001_3" value="30"/>
        <MC machine="psys_CAA001_4" value="40"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="124" name="Sheet X" desc="Sheet length in the X direction." type="r" ord="12" value="2500">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="125" name="Sheet Y" desc="Sheet length in the Y direction." type="r" ord="13" value="1250">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    </Group> 
    </RadanAttributes>
</RadanCompoundDocument>
```

Thanks!
Tibi

I not work similar xml before.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? If you haven't tried anything then you haven't encountered an issue yet. There is plenty of information around about reading data from XML. Don't just ignore it. You need to do what you can for yourself first, then ask about what you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlDocument.SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?source=recommendations&view=net-6.0) with a fitting [XPath expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to retrieve a list of matching nodes [XmlNodeList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist?view=net-6.0)

Something like

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
xmlDoc.Load("MyFile.xml")

Dim xmlNodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//RadanCompoundDocument/RadanAttributes/Group/Attr/MC")

For i As Int32 = 0 To xmlNodes.Cound -1
   Dim xmlNode As XmlNode = xmlNodes.Item(i)
   ' Do stuff with the individual "MC" node
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Xml Serialization

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME)
        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(RadanCompoundDocument))
        Dim document As RadanCompoundDocument = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
    End Sub


End Module
<XmlRoot(Namespace:="http://www.radan.com/ns/rcd")>
Public Class RadanCompoundDocument
    <XmlArray(ElementName:="RadanAttributes")>
    <XmlArrayItem(ElementName:="Group")>
    Public Group As List(Of Group)
End Class
Public Class Group
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="class")>
    Public xClass As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="desc")>
    Public desc As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="name")>
    Public name As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Attr")>
    Public attr As List(Of Attr)
End Class
Public Class Attr
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="num")>
    Public num As Integer
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="name")>
    Public name As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="desc")>
    Public desc As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="type")>
    Public type As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="ord")>
    Public ord As Integer
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="value")>
    Public value As String

End Class
```